# ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH - nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have created my SSL certificate as follows:

```
openssl ecparam -name secp521r1 -genkey -param_enc explicit -out domain.com.key
openssl req -new -sha256 -key domain.com.key -out domain.com.csr -config domain-csr.conf
```

i got the `domain.com.csr` file from which my SSL provider sent me the bundle and crt files.

but when i view the site i get the `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`

my nginx.conf is:

```
server {
    server_name {{ $host }};
    listen 443 ssl http2 {{ $default_server }};
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA;
```

here are the logs:

```
ccc@zapotec ~/nginx-proxy $ docker logs nginx-proxy-server
WARNING: /etc/nginx/dhparam/dhparam.pem was not found. A pre-generated dhparam.pem will be used for now while a new one
is being generated in the background.  Once the new dhparam.pem is in place, nginx will be reloaded.
forego     | starting dockergen.1 on port 5000
forego     | starting nginx.1 on port 5100
dockergen.1 | 2017/10/13 11:50:18 Generated '/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf' from 14 containers
dockergen.1 | 2017/10/13 11:50:18 Running 'nginx -s reload'
dockergen.1 | 2017/10/13 11:50:18 Watching docker events
nginx.1    | 2017/10/13 11:50:18 [crit] 37#37: *20 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1417D102:SSL routines:tls_process_client_hello:unsupported protocol) while SSL handshaking, client: 195.39.86.27, server: 0.0.0.0:443
nginx.1    | 2017/10/13 11:50:18 [crit] 37#37: *21 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1417D102:SSL routines:tls_process_client_hello:unsupported protocol) while SSL handshaking, client: 195.39.86.27, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

what am i missing?

any advise is much appreciated.

Comment: output of `$ openssl version`?

Comment: `ccc@zapotec /ccc $ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
`

Comment: I can not see any configuration of the certificates in the nginx.conf. Did you omit it from the question or are they really missing from the configuration? Also, have you looked at the error logs from the server?

Comment: output of `$ nginx -v`?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `ssl_ciphers` to the following:

```
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256;
```

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Modern_compatibility